# JSON Schema not validating required attributes

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

Here is the criteria: the individual region object can co-exist withing the array along with ONLY asia/europe/austrlia (either one region at a time from asia/europe/austrlia).

In addition to this every region object can have few required attributes and nested one.

The issue is the schema validator is not complaining about the required attribute (i.e. width attribute from dimension object)

Here is the JSON Schema

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "properties": {
    "stat_data": {
      "type": "array",
      "if": {
        "contains": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "region": {
              "type": "string",
              "enum": [
                "europe"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "then": {
        "not": {
          "contains": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "region": {
                "type": "string",
                "enum": [
                  "asia",
                  "australia"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "else": {
        "if": {
          "contains": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "region": {
                "type": "string",
                "enum": [
                  "asia"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "then": {
          "not": {
            "contains": {
              "type": "object",
              "properties": {
                "region": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "enum": [
                    "europe",
                    "australia"
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "else": {
          "if": {
            "contains": {
              "type": "object",
              "properties": {
                "region": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "enum": [
                    "australia"
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "then": {
            "not": {
              "contains": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                  "region": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "enum": [
                      "europe",
                      "asia"
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "else": {}
        }
      },
      "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "details": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/dimension"
          },
          "population": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/details"
          },
          "dimension": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/population"
          },
          "region": {
            "enum": [
              "asia",
              "europe",
              "australia",
              "some-pencil-region",
              "some-oil-pastels-region"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "definitions": {
    "dimension": {
      "type": "object",
      "required": [
        "width"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "height": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "width": {
          "type": "integer"
        }
      }
    },
    "details": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "brand": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "year": {
          "type": "integer"
        }
      }
    },
    "population": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "change": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "year": {
          "type": "integer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and the JSON

```
{
  "stat_data": [
    {
      "region": "some-pencil-region",
      "details": {
        "brand": "Camlin",
        "year": 2019
      }
    },
    {
      "region": "some-oil-pastels-region",
      "height": 30
    },
    {
      "region": "asia",
      "population": {
        "year": 2018,
        "change": 2
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

You can check at _https://jsonschema.dev/ by copying schema and json in the editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your JSON validator doesn't catch the issue? [JSONBuddy](https://json-buddy.com) shows a message about a missing "width" property:

[image]